# Replace text in SQL

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a field called EMAIL_ADDRESS. One of the records would be:

```
john@gmail.com, mike@gmail.com, joe@yahoo.com, george@yahoo.com, fred@gmail.com
```

I wan to remove all yahoo addresses in my SELECT query to get:

```
john@gmail.com, mike@gmail.com, fred@gmail.com
```

If I use

```
REPLACE(SM.SCORECARD_EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'joe@yahoo.com,', '')
```

this works.

If I want to remove ALL yahoo email addresses this doesn't work:

```
REPLACE(SM.SCORECARD_EMAIL_ADDRESS, '%@yahoo.com,', '')
```

because wildcards don't seem to work as it's looking for % in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably fix your table design and stop storing CSV lists of email addresses.  Instead, get each email onto a separate record.  As a short term fix, if you're running MySQL 8+, you may use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = REGEXP_REPLACE(
                        REGEXP_REPLACE(EMAIL_ADDRESS, '(, )?\\S+@yahoo\\.com,?', ','), '^,+|,+$', '')
WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS LIKE '%@yahoo.com%';
```

Comment: I am not looking to update the table, I just want it in my SELECT query for a report I am creating.

Comment: Then select the `REGEXP_REPLACE` term in my update query.

Comment: OK, I am doing more research on it now, this seems like the way to go thank you. I think there's something missing in the REGEXP_REPLACE you posted maybe, I am getting an error, trying to troubleshoot.......

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to udpate records but you want them only in the SELECT query you can use `NOT LIKE` operator

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE email NOT LIKE '%yahoo.com'
```

So you get records that doesn’t match the like pattern